# Problems with VS19 ToolBox framework 4.5.2

Tags: controls, visual-studio-2019, .net-framework-version, toolbox

I have a .Dll project full of Controls for Winforms:
Platform : x86
.Net Framework : 4.5.2

Since yesterday it started to have problems when i add it to the toolbox of any other project with the same .Net framework version. It won't let me use it in the Designer

---

This message show up every time i try to add it to the ToolBox
[image: TooBox Message]

2 days ago everything was fine and it worked in the Designer, i could drag and drop all the Controls in the .Dll

---

Something strange is that i can still use all the controls from code by typing:

```
var ctrl = new CustomControls()....
this.Controls.Add(ctrl)
```

It's just the toolBox that sucks.

---

I already tried:

- Restarting VS
- Rebuild Dll and other project
- Reset ToolBox
- Delete and Add the Dll to project References

---

PS: yestarday I updated w11 update, and it was refeating to .Net framework

Restarting VS
Rebuild Dll and other project
Reset ToolBox
Delete and Add the Dll to project References